# No such method exception on EMR Spark 1.4.1.a with custom authentication

Tags: authentication, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, emr

I am setting up custom authentication for SparkSQL on thriftserver running on EMR cluster.

I get NoSuchMethodException.

Exception:

```
15/09/25 01:59:29 ERROR server.TThreadPoolServer: Error occurred during processing of message.
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.hive.service.auth.PasswdAuthenticationProvider.<init>()
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:131)
    at org.apache.hive.service.auth.CustomAuthenticationProviderImpl.<init>(CustomAuthenticationProviderImpl.java:38)
    at org.apache.hive.service.auth.AuthenticationProviderFactory.getAuthenticationProvider(AuthenticationProviderFactory.java:62)
```

Hive-site:

```
  <property>
      <name>hive.server2.authentication</name>
      <value>CUSTOM</value>
   </property>
   <property>
      <name>HIVE_SERVER2_CUSTOM_AUTHENTICATION_CLASS</name>
      <value>package.Authenticator</value>
   </property>  
   <property>
      <name>hive.server2.enable.doAs</name>
      <value>false</value>
   </property>
```

EMR infrastructure:

```
AMI version:3.8.0
Hadoop distribution:Amazon 2.4.0
Applications: Ganglia, Hive latest, Hue, Spark
```

thrift-server-start command:

```
/home/hadoop/spark/sbin/start-thriftserver.sh --master yarn --deploy-mode client --executor-cores 7 --num-executors 2 --executor-memory 44G --driver-java-options -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled --driver-java-options -XX:MaxPermSize=1g --driver-cores 4 --driver-memory 10g --properties-file /home/hadoop/spark-overrides.properties --jars /home/hadoop/spark/classpath/emr/authenticator-0.1.jar
```

spark-properties:

```
spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max.mb=256
spark.scheduler.mode=FAIR
spark.rdd.compress=true
spark.cleaner.ttl=604800
spark.driver.maxResultSize=2g
spark.shuffle.consolidateFiles=true
spark.shuffle.file.buffer.kb=256
spark.speculation=true
spark.speculation.interval=1000
spark.io.compression.codec=lz4
spark.sql.thriftserver.scheduler.pool=sql
spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=200
spark.authenticate=false
```

hive-service is at 0.13.1
Is there anything else I should be doing.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well... things were supposed to be(at least with spark 1.4.1 on emr cluster):

```
<property>
   <name>hive.server2.authentication</name>
   <value>CUSTOM</value>
</property>
<property>
   <name>hive.server2.custom.authentication.class</name>
   <value>my-authenticator</value>
</property>
```

Comment: Yes, changing HIVE_SERVER2_CUSTOM_AUTHENTICATION_CLASS to hive.server2.custom.authentication.class did the trick at least on the emr cluster.